# Stack Overflow Jobs categorization

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Why don't you add categories for jobs to filter?

It is ridiculous that trying to find a backend job I got frontend jobs.

[image]

Comment: What kinds of categories? You need to be a bit more specific than just "categories".

Comment: Or, do you mean something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wlg9q.png)?

Comment: @Oded, thank you, looks like you are right.
The problem is that I don't know why people who post jobs add wrong tags (e.g. for front-end position tag full-stack and no front-end)

Comment: @Kanu we are grinding our gears hard to fix this problem. Employers are bad at tagging jobs, and automatically tagging jobs (with high accuracy) is challenging.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my mistake. The problem was with wrong tags in vacancy descrition